# RDS snapshots to S3 key policy

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

I am using CDK to implement a mechanism to automatically export my Snapshots to S3.

However, I am facing an issue with the KMS key policy.

I already know which Actions I need, I am just not sure of the Principal who should get them. No matter what I did, I always end up with this error:

> An error occurred (KMSKeyNotAccessibleFault) when calling the
> CopyDBSnapshot operation: The target snapshot KMS key [] does
> not exist, is not enabled or you do not have permission to access it.

After manually manipulating the key policy, I found out that this one actually works:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::100701839197:root"
        },
        "Action": "kms:*",
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": [
            "kms:Encrypt",
            "kms:Decrypt",
            "kms:ReEncrypt*",
            "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
            "kms:CreateGrant",
            "kms:DescribeKey",
            "kms:RetireGrant"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

But this is too broad for a key policy that is only used for RDS snapshot exports, I tried to add the following principles instead but nothing seems to work for me:

> export.rds.amazonaws.com

> rds.amazonaws.com

> lambda.amazonaws.com

I also tried to    `exportLambda.role?.addToPrincipalPolicy(kmsPolicy)`
But this also does not seem to work.
My code is very simple, I create the KMS key, the KMS policy, and the Lambda, which calls the `ExportTaskCommand` where I am giving the `KmsKeyId`.